# Llamar a plugin mediante jquery [data-widget]

Tags: javascript, jquery, adminlte

Muy buenas, estoy utilizando la plantilla AdminLTE y quiero que, al abrir una página, se abra en pantalla completa. Hay un icono con enlace y data-widget="fullscreen" que hace esto pero no puedo simular su llamada mediante jquery. El código de dicho botón es este:

```
     <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" data-widget="fullscreen" href="javascript:;" role="button" id="BtnFullScreen">
                <i class="fas fa-expand-arrows-alt"></i>
              </a>
            </li>
```

El js al que quiero llamar contiene el siguiente código:

```
/**
 * --------------------------------------------
 * AdminLTE Fullscreen.js
 * License MIT
 * --------------------------------------------
 */

import $ from 'jquery'

/**
 * Constants
 * ====================================================
 */

const NAME = 'Fullscreen'
const DATA_KEY = 'lte.fullscreen'
const JQUERY_NO_CONFLICT = $.fn[NAME]

const SELECTOR_DATA_WIDGET = '[data-widget="fullscreen"]'
const SELECTOR_ICON = `${SELECTOR_DATA_WIDGET} i`

const EVENT_FULLSCREEN_CHANGE = 'webkitfullscreenchange mozfullscreenchange fullscreenchange MSFullscreenChange'

const Default = {
  minimizeIcon: 'fa-compress-arrows-alt',
  maximizeIcon: 'fa-expand-arrows-alt'
}

/**
 * Class Definition
 * ====================================================
 */

class Fullscreen {
  constructor(_element, _options) {
    this.element = _element
    this.options = $.extend({}, Default, _options)
  }

  ... Lo corto porque sino no puedo enviar la pregunta...
```

Como puedo invocarlo? Gracias de antemano.